Functions with restrictive behavior on $\mathbb{S}^2$
Let $ f $ be a smooth function defined on the sphere such that the set of points where $ f(x) - f(\tilde{x}_y) $ vanishes divides $\mathbb{S}^2$ into exactly four regions (connected open sets) for all $y\in \mathbb{S}^2$, with a uniform lower bounded on the areas of those regions, where $\tilde{x}_y $ is the reflection of $ x $ with respect to the plane $ P_y $ passing through the origin with normal vector $ y $.
I believe such a function does not exist. My idea is to use Borsuk-Ulam type theorems to prove it. However, I have not been successful in doing so. Any hints would be appreciated.

Here’s an idea: Let $y \in \mathbb{S}^2$, and define $\Omega_{+}$ as the unique region where $f(x) - f(\tilde{x}_y) > 0$ that also lies on the same side of $y$ with respect to the plane $P_y$. Choose an orthogonal coordinate system $\{v_1, v_2, y\}$, where points are represented by the coordinates $(a,b,c)$ in this system. Now, let $g$ be a function defined on $\mathbb{S}^2$, and compute the weighted center of mass on the region $\Omega_+$ as follows:
$$
F(y) = (c_a, c_b, 0) = \left( \frac{\int_{\Omega_+} a g(a,b,c) \, dA}{\int_{\Omega_+} g(a,b,c) \, dA}, \frac{\int_{\Omega_+} b g(a,b,c) \, dA}{\int_{\Omega_+} g(a,b,c) \, dA}, 0 \right).
$$
Note that the definition of the center of mass is independent of the choice of the coordinates system, and $F(y)$ is tangent to the sphere at the point $y$. Hence, if there exists a function $g$ such that $F(y) \neq 0$, this would contradict the Hairy Ball Theorem. The question then becomes: is it possible that, for any choice of $g$, the function $F(y)$ will always have a zero? Intuitively, the space of functions on the sphere seems rich enough to include a function $g$ such that the center of mass $F(y)$ never vanishes. The challenge now is: can we find such a $g$?

What prompted this conjecture?

@FShrike I was playing with spherical harmonics and symmetric functions on the sphere, and thought I could construct a function which is not symmetric about any plane, but satisfies this condition, but I found it impossible. That's why I think the result might be true.

How about $f(x,y,z) = yz$, with the reflection defined by flipping the sign of $z$ (ie. plane is defined by z = 0).

By region, do you mean a connected (open?) subset?

@FShrike Yes, a connected open set.

@user3257842 In your example the zero set become the whole $S^2$ when doing reflection with respect to $x=0$, which is not allowed by our assumption.

Do you know of an example where the uniform lower bound is the only condition that fails?

@Keplerto No, but I thought enforcing it may be needed for the result to be true as it may exclude some weird scenarios.

I've found an impossibility argument that assumes each of the four regions is simply connected for any choice of $y$ (relying on the properties of the $2$ intersection points of their boundaries), unfortunately it does not seem to generalize if we drop that assumption.

@user3257842 Yes, assuming that the regions are simply connected, the problems becomes much easier and I also have an argument based on the two intersection points on the boundary.

@FShrike I have included and idea which seems promising to me. I would appreciate if you could take a look.

@user3257842 I have included and idea which seems promising to me. I would appreciate if you could take a look.

I want to make sure I understand what you mean by "uniform lower bound" - is it something different than a lower bound on the areas of the regions you can generate? Does the "uniform" condition somehow imply the bound is $> 0$?

@MartianInvader It means that there exists a $C>0$, such that the area of all connected components are bigger than $C$, for all $y\in \mathbb{S}^2$.
